# Does DNS over HTTPS work in China?

Tags: networking, dns, firewall

DNS over HTTPS is a new technology that encrypts your DNS lookups, so that your ISP cannot see what domain names you are trying to visit. Firefox enabled it by default for me yesterday. I would like to know if this feature will work normally in China, or if it is blocked by the Great Firewall. Thanks!

Comment: In my experience, deep packet inspection (or something like that) can at least cause things to fail from time to time. And in any case, the GFW does way more than MITM on name resolution. (So I wouldn't even bother to find out how well it works.)

Comment: Relevant XKCD: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/security.png

Comment: @Gantendo HAHAHAHAHA, you made my day! I know from experience that social engineering is in fact the easiest way to get someone's password!

Comment: @FelixAn Have you tried violence? The Chinese government has...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. They block anything they can't easily monitor.

> This situation changed with the recent introduction of DoH and ESNI –
> technologies that made DNS lookups fully encrypted and therefore
> censor resistant.
>
> John ‘Turbo’ Conwell, principal data scientist at DomainTools,
> explained: “This means that anyone monitoring DNS traffic wouldn’t be
> able to see what domains are being resolved.
>
> “This posed a problem for China, prompting them to make a change… to
> their Great Firewall to block all TLS 1.3 and ESNI traffic,
> effectively stopping people in China from using DoH to hide their DNS
> lookups.”

https://portswigger.net/daily-swig/cat-and-mouse-privacy-advocates-fight-back-after-china-tightens-surveillance-controls

https://www.zdnet.com/article/china-is-now-blocking-all-encrypted-https-traffic-using-tls-1-3-and-esni/

This paper is a bit outdated but quite interesting nonetheless. https://www.usenix.org/system/files/sec21-hoang.pdf